# Object conversion with vectors

Tags: r, integer, numeric

I run given code:

```
> mean(as.numeric(x <- 1:4))
[1] 2.5
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
> 
> x <- 2:5
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
> as.numeric(x)
[1] 2 3 4 5
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
>
```

**Query -** As far as I have studied for an object to behave like an `integer` it has to be assigned `L` in the end, but over here, I see completely a different story. So, why the classes of `x` and `y` are not `numeric`?

However, without vector things go as usual:

```
> a <-3
> class(a)
[1] "numeric"
> b <- 3L
> class(b)
[1] "integer"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we check the `?":"`, it is already described

> For numeric arguments, a numeric vector. This will be of type integer
>   if from is integer-valued and the result is representable in the R
>   integer type, otherwise of type "double" (aka mode "numeric").

Here, `2` and `5` are integers and so the sequence will also be `integer` call.  Of course type promotion is there in dynamic languages as opposed to static languages

Also, check the output of

```
class(seq(2, 5))
#[1] "integer"
class(seq(2.0, 5.0))
#[1] "integer"
class(seq(2.0, 5.0, by = 1.0))
#[1] "numeric"
class(seq(2, 5, by = 1.0))
#[1] "numeric"
class(seq(2, 5, by = 1))
#[1] "numeric"
class(seq(2, 5, by = 1L))
#[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Also, note that the OP doesn't assign the output of `as.numeric(x)`, so `x` is unchanged and still of class `integer`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  My point is that it will be class `integer` for integer elements unless we specify the `by` because `by = ((to - from)/(length.out - 1))`,

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I just noted that, in the example code he gave,  the OP does `as.numeric/class` in a row. Many times this means that the class of the object is expected to change.